# Зажать и динамически растянуть(сжать) View-элемент

Tags: java, android

У меня есть контейнер(RecycleView) с некоторыми внутренностями.
Он находится между тулбаром(Toolbar) и линией(ImageView), которая снизу к нему прикреплена.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог свободно зажимать эту линию(или нижнюю часть контейнера) и водить ею вверх и вниз экрана, при этом динамически изменялась высота контейнера, к которому линия прикреплена.
"Зажать и растянуть" другими словами.

Пока что я написал метод, который скрывает контейнер, если он активен, и делает его активным, если он скрыт. Что меня не устраивает в полной мере.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.